# How do I organize strings into a table in visual c#?

Tags: c#

I was trying to sort up strings into grids in Visual c#, but couldn't do it. What code do I need to do so?

I've already tried going to many websites and writing the code specified, but it did not work.

I was expecting at least something, but all I got was a blank table when I copied code from a website.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{   
   // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'vendorDataSet.Vendor' table.   
   // You can move, or remove it, as needed.  
   this.vendorTableAdapter.Fill(this.vendorDataSet.Vendor);  
}
```

Comment: please show us some code or tell us what do you want accurately

Comment: can  you please share your example code what you have already tried? or provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I am 11 years old and a newbie in programming. I followed the steps on c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/…. I expected a full table but all I got was a blank one. The code I used is in my question.

Comment: "I've already tried going to many websites and writing the code specified, but it did not work." - show us the code you tried and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: The code in your question isn't anywhere near complete. Can you provide us all the relevant code?

Comment: I checked the url ("c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/") in your comment, but I found nothing. The website gives a "page not found" response. Since the url does not seem to work, I cannot check what you already did. Can you please check the url?

Comment: What parts of this have you completed? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/datagridview-control-in-c-sharp/

Comment: I finished all of the steps. @ Gokhan thanks for the code.Looks like it works. @Bart Hofland the url seems to work. Maybe it was down when you checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you want: You have some strings (ie in an array) and you want to insert them into a DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1",typeof(string));
foreach(string str in yourStringArray){
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["Column1"]= str;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
}
```